# How to add extra property in MKAnnotation swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add extra property into MKAnnotation in Swift. Now i can use property like title, subtitle or coordinate. I want to add property for example extraTitle to store some text. I don't know how to write some extension :( Can You help me?

Comment: whats your trying code? whats the output?

Comment: I'm new with swift and I don't know how to write extension with new property, I read about it but I didn't find answer 
'extension MKAnnotation {
let extraString: String?
}' don't work i have error that Extension may not contain stored properties

Comment: You will need to subclass MKAnnotation. You can't use an extension as you have found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MKAnnotation is a protocol. You can define a class which implements the protocol properties, and adds anything extra you want.

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject,MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var extraTitle: String?
    init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```